# Android Colors in Dark Mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, themes, android-darkmode

Hello fellow developers.

I've developed and Android App using **Android Studio**, but I only took into account the layout themes for **light** mode. Here's how it looks:

[image: light mode]

So now, when I switch my phone to **dark** mode, this happens:

[image: dark mode]

How can I change the colors that are being displayed in **dark mode**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `res/values/colors`
There are two colors
`colors.xml`
`colors.xml(night)`

---

If night does not exist, you can make it as follows:
Right click on the `values` folder.
Next `New`. Then `Values Resource file`
Enter the `colors`  in the `file name` field
And enter the `values-night` in the `directory name` field.

---

In colors.xml, select the colors that are for the light, such as:

```xml
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorButton">#303F9F</color>
```

In colors.xml(night), set the colors for the night(Same name as colors):

```xml
<color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000000</color> 
<color name="colorButton">#10ffffff</color>
```

Now if in layout, for example:

```xml
<Button
     android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android: background = "@color/colorButton" />
```

It is selected according to what you put in the light and night colors.

Comment: If you do not manually color some of the views in the layout, it uses the default value. This default value is defined in the manifest theme. For example theme = "...". You can in the theme directory or in the style directory . Create a style tag and change the default values(Ex. primaryColor) inside and give it a manifest theme.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Use the folders:

```
/values/
/values-night/
```

It mentions it here as well: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#config-changes

"night-qualified resources"

```
Your themes and styles should avoid hard-coded colors or icons intended for use under a light theme. You should use theme attributes (preferred) or night-qualified resources instead.
```